# How to create a grid of 3d objects without making them actual GameObjects

Tags: unity, gameobject, efficiency

Very simple question:
If I'm going to be generating and placing a lot of 3d objects (in this case cubes), that are not going to be interactive, like no collision, no raycasting intersections etc.  Should they be GameObjects or is there a lighter solution that doesn't inherit the GameObject blob?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GameObjects don't really prove to be that big of an overhead. Just make sure you are using a material with GPU Instancing enabled.

[image: How to enabled GPU Instancing]

However, if you want to avoid GameObjects anyway, you can instead use the `Graphics` class. Specifically [`Graphics.DrawMeshInstanced`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.DrawMeshInstanced.html). You just need a reference to a Mesh and Material, as well as an array of matrices that indicate where to draw each one. Something like this:

```
public class DrawCubes : MonoBehaviour {
  public Mesh cube;
  public int submeshIndex;  //If the mesh has more than one submesh, specify which one to draw. Normally this can be left as 0.
  public Material material; //Note: This material must have instancing enabled.

  private Matrix4x4[] locations;
  void Start() {
    locations = new Matrix4x4[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < locations.length; ++i) {
      //Position at (i,0,0), no rotation, with no scaling
      locations[i] = Matrix4x4.TRS(new Vector3(i,0,0), Quaternion.identity, Vector3.one);
    }
  }
  void Update() {
    Graphics.DrawMeshInstanced(cube, submeshIndex, material, matrices);
  }
}
```

A few notes, from Unity's documentation:

> Meshes are not further culled by the view frustum or baked occluders, nor sorted for transparency or z efficiency.

And

> You can only draw a maximum of 1023 instances at once.

Also

> InvalidOperationException will be thrown if the current platform doesn't support this API (i.e. if GPU instancing is not available). See [SystemInfo.supportsInstancing](https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-supportsInstancing.html).

If instancing is not supported, while you can still draw one at a time, using `Graphics.DrawMesh`, this is actually going to be less performant than using GameObjects, because this method does not use batching.

Finally, there are many overrides to `DrawMeshInstanced` to check out which add other features, like MaterialPropertyBlock overrides per instance.

Comment: Wow that's a fantastic answer, i'll dig into it when I have the chance! Thanks!